# Redraw Label Control In VBa

Tags: vba, label, redraw

Is it possible to repaint the form for only one control. That is I need to increase the width of a label. but while repainting the form, the form totally refreshing. that looks like the form is blinking. So I need to redraw the label only. Please help me

Comment: A simple resize should not cause noticeable flicker, what are you doing exactly?

Comment: I increases thize of a label to work like a progress bar

Answer (score 3):

Instead of formName.Repaint I tried with "DoEvents". It worked for me.

```
formCreateAndValidate.lblPgrsBar.Width = prgrsLblWidth
DoEvents
```

Comment: I'm updating a TextBox's DisplayAsHyperlink property on a form's OnCurrent event, and it does not seem to take effect. Calling DoEvents unfortunately does not resolve the issue. I will continue searching for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of *Repaint* (which is slow indeed) I recommend using this pair of lines to refresh a control:

```
myControl.Visible = False
myControl.Visible = True
```

It is much faster. Invisible state is so short that it behaves very smoothly.

It also works for me where *DoEvents* doesn't. E.g. in a class that has *WithEvents* attribute to handle control's events and change its appearence.
Hope it helps!